# Creating a plugin for WooCommerce: Adding an option tab to API settings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I am creating a plugin for Worpdress/WooCommerce. I have done all the stuff and now I want to add an option tab to woocommerce API settings, like in this [**instruction tutorial**](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/adding-a-section-to-a-settings-tab/).

This is my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sections_api', 'some_function_to_add_tab' );

function some_function_to_add_tab( $sections ) {
    $sections['some_settings'] = __( 'Some Settings', 'text-domain' );
    return $sections;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_api', 'some_tab_settings', 10, 2 );

function some_tab_settings( $settings, $current_section ) {
    if ($current_section == 'some_settings') {
        echo "settings here";
    } else {
        return $settings;
    }
}
```

But I am getting some errors:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for some_tab_settings() in C:\OpenServer\domains\wp-dev\wp-content\plugins\some-plugin\some_plugin.php on line 30
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: current_section in C:\OpenServer\domains\wp-dev\wp-content\plugins\some-plugin\some_plugin.php on line 31

Related to:

> add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_api', 'some_tab_settings', 10, 2 );  ==> **Line: 30**
>
> function some_tab_settings( $settings, $current_section ) { ==> **Line: 31**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have one more question :) Can u explain how can i use the form in tutorial to insert data to dabase? like am writing something in input clicking "save" button and data inserting to my table. I now how to insert, but not how to use the form that created by array ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking first at the core source code of [**WC for WooCommerce API Settings**](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/settings/class-wc-settings-api.php) and to [**this useful only tutorial**](http://www.w3bdeveloper.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-new-settings-tab-in-wordpress-woocommerce-admin-area/) (2016) I have found on the subject. Here is the code:

```
// creating a new sub tab in API settings
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sections_api','add_subtab' );
function add_subtab( $settings_tabs ) {
    $settings_tabs['custom_settings'] = __( 'Custom Settings', 'woocommerce-custom-settings-tab' );
    return $settings_tabs;
}


// adding settings (HTML Form)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_api', 'add_subtab_settings', 10, 2 );
function add_subtab_settings( $settings ) {
    $current_section = (isset($_GET['section']) && !empty($_GET['section']))? $_GET['section']:'';
    if ( $current_section == 'custom_settings' ) {
        $custom_settings = array();
        $custom_settings[] = array( 'name' => __( 'Custom Settings', 'text-domain' ), 
                                   'type' => 'title', 
                                   'desc' => __( 'The following options are used to ...', 'text-domain' ), 
                                   'id' => 'custom_settings'
                                  );

        $custom_settings[] = array(
                                    'name'     => __( 'Field 1', 'text-domain' ),
                                    'id'       => 'field_one',
                                    'type'     => 'text',
                                    'default'  => get_option('field_one'),

                                );

        $custom_settings[] = array( 'type' => 'sectionend', 'id' => 'test-options' );             
        return $custom_settings;
    } else {
        // If not, return the standard settings
        return $settings;
    }
}
```

It's used to create a new tab and a sub tab in woocommerce settings tab API. the second function displays HTML fields where you will be able to edit and save the settings.

Thanks to [Daniel Halmagean](https://plus.google.com/113045708943310441142/posts)

---

**Update:** Using the New Settings:

You would now just use your newly created settings like you would any other WordPress / WooCommerce setting, through the `get_option()` function and the defined ID of the setting (see reference below).

For example if your settings `array` id is `'custom_settings'` you will use `get_option( 'custom_settings' )`. For more specific information on adding settings to WooCommerce, check out the [wooThemes: Settings API](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/settings-api/). May be you can use `echo var_dump();` function to see the outputted data:

```
$my_data = get_option( 'custom_settings' );
echo var_dump( $my_data );
```

---

Reference:

- [wooThemes: Adding a Section to a Settings Tab](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/adding-a-section-to-a-settings-tab/)
- [wooThemes: Settings API](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/settings-api/)

Comment: Didnt really understand how to use this form :(. But i will continue to read documentaion :) thanx

Answer (score 0):

Please try this with "woocommerce_get_settings_products" hook. You can not get current section from this( woocommerce_get_sections_api ) hook.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_products', 'some_tab_settings', 10, 2 );

function some_tab_settings( $settings, $current_section ) {
    if ($current_section == 'some_settings') {
        echo "settings here";
    } else {
        return $settings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add this hook add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sections_products', 'some_function_to_add_tab' );

function some_function_to_add_tab( $sections ) {
    $sections['some_settings'] = __( 'Some Settings', 'text-domain' );
    return $sections;
}

Comment: This filter adding option to products tab. But i need a settings tab in the API section.

Comment: Sorry for mistake. please use this without current section. woocommerce manage this current section by default. add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_api', 'some_tab_settings', 10, 2 );
function some_tab_settings( $settings ) {
        echo "settings here";
        return $settings;
}

Comment: `function syncretailcrm_settings( $settings) {
 if ($_GET['section'] == 'some_settings') {
  adminMenu();
 } else {
  return $settings;
 }
}`
I did the following and now getting this error when going to settings tab: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\OpenServer\domains\wp-dev\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\class-wc-admin-settings.php on line 222`

Comment: what do you want to use syncretailcrm_settings this function.

Comment: Now im having this `add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sections_api', 'sync_retail_crm' );

function sync_retail_crm( $sections ) {
 $sections['syncretailcrm'] = __( 'Sync RetailCRM', 'text-domain' );
 return $sections;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_api', 'syncretailcrm_settings', 10, 2 );

function syncretailcrm_settings( $settings ) {
 adminMenu();
 return $settings;
}
`
and i want to go to my settings by clicking my section but not the settings button which going first